# cURL issue when trying to post to Gravity Form on external site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, curl

I have two SEPARATE sites:

- Site A: A Wordpress site which has a Gravity Form.
- Site B: A non-Wordpress site which hosts a simple form - the data from this form needs to end up at Site A's Gravity Form (which also needs to auto-submit in this instance).

I'm currently using cURL to post to the external site, but none of my test entries are showing up in the Gravity Form and curl_exec() is just returning the entire html of the page on the external site.

Here's my current code:

```
<form name="test" method="post">              
<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" /></p>
<p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" /></p>
<p>Address: <input type="text" name="address" /></p>
<p>City: <input type="text" name="city" /></p>
<p>State: <select name="state">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
    <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
    <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="California">California</option>
    <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
    <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
    <option value="District of Columbia">District of Columbia</option>
    <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
    <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
    <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
    <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
    <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
    <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
    <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
    <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
    <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
    <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
    <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
    <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="New York">New York</option>
    <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
    <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
    <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
    <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
    <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
    <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
    <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
    <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
    <option value="Armed Forces Americas">Armed Forces Americas</option><option value="Armed Forces Europe">Armed Forces Europe</option>
    <option value="Armed Forces Pacific">Armed Forces Pacific</option>
    </select></p>
<p>Zipcode: <input type="text" name="zip" /></p>
<p>Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" /></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

```
<?php
$email = urlencode($_POST['email']);
$fname = urlencode($_POST['firstName']);
$lname = urlencode($_POST['lastName']);
$address = urlencode($_POST['address']);
$city = urlencode($_POST['city']);
$state = urlencode($_POST['state']);
$zip = urlencode($_POST['zip']);

$submit_url = "http://location/of/my/gravity/form/";

$data = array(
'f_name'=>$fname,
'l_name'=>$lname,
'add1'=>$address,
'city'=>$city,
'state'=>$state,
'zip'=>$zip,
'email'=>$email,
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $submit_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
curl_close ($ch);

?>
```

Comment: What is your output on $result ? is there anything in your error log ?

Comment: $result prints the html of the target page (my $submit_url), and there's nothing new in my apache error log

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not using [`http_build_query`](http://www.php.net/http_build_query)

```
  $data = array(
    'f_name'=>$fname,
    'l_name'=>$lname,
    'add1'=>$address,
    'city'=>$city,
    'state'=>$state,
    'zip'=>$zip,
    'email'=>$email,
    ); 



    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($chAgain, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Same exact result :( it's the entry doesn't get populated in the external Gravity Form and if I echo the result of curl_exec, it's just the html of the target URL.